# Task Scheduler running a Program incorrectly

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas, windows-task-scheduler, python3, tasks

I have created a python exe that copies data from a NAS to a external HDD.

This is on a Windows sever 2012 and the NAS and External is accessible to use. Also using the user account with full admin rights. The Task Scheduler is also set to use highest privilege's when start a program is used.

When I let the task scheduler run the program, I get a email notification that it cant find the source file (on NAS).

When I run the program manually it works. I see the data in the external HDD location. Email response Successful.

What would cause the task scheduler to not let the program work like it does when used manually?

Regards,
Johan

Comment: Tell us how the NAS share is defined and how the python program refers to it.

Comment: Hey, I am not 100% on how to respond but here goes:

NAS - source_path = r"\\X-DRIVE-NAS-\SQL Backup\Daily"
Ext HDD - target_path = r"\\X-DRIVE-NAS\StoreJet_Transcend-1\SQL Backup\Daily"